# Need advice on starting up with Dugundji

Tags: general-topology

I am learning topology. As of now I can say that I have gone through basic definitions of topology and basic arguments. I guess the questions in my profile do speak of the level of novice at it. I have got Dugundji's book with me and after going through learning via lecture notes, I thought I should start up with this textbook now. But The first two chapters are about set theory and ordinal numbers (I am interested to learn about this topic but for the time being I need to progress in topology). I would like advice if I could skip the first two chapters without developing a conceptual hole and proceed to the further chapters.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should read Chapter I, except Section 8 (Axiomatics), but you should read Section 9 (General cartesian products), which is used to define the product topology. Chapter I should be easy to read if you are already familiar with operations on sets. If you don't, it is mandatory to first master it before going any further. You can probably skip Chapter II on ordinals, but be aware that some examples/proofs may refer to this chapter soon or later.

Comment: I concur. I think that the first thing from Chapter II that’s actually needed is some of the notation from Section I.8 on cardinal arithmetic, namely, that Dugundji uses $\aleph(A)$ for what I would write $|A|$, the cardinality of $A$.